# Linked CSS and jquery.html()

Tags: jquery, html, css

Whenver I dynamically replace the html of a element using [jquery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/), no external css (excluding those inheriting from parent elements) gets applied into the elements. By external css, I mean those not directly input into the page via style tag (without src property).

Is there a way to make them apply?

Comment: really?? can you give an example scenario??

Comment: Answered below. It was a sass content type thing, which obviously didn't happen when the style was inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should apply. You're probably deleting a necessary element which is required by the styles in order to apply. We could confirm it if you had posted your code.

Comment: It was a problem with the content-type of a sass generated css. You are right, it works perfectly.